# How to run build_runner to correctly generate these "g2" partial files?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to make enhancements to the following project

https://pub.dev/packages/swagger_dart_code_generator

It contains classes that are annotated with @JsonSerializable, and these classes are what I need modify.
When I run build_runner (to generate the partial json classes) - it will attempt to create ".g.dart" partial files. However, this project has somehow managed to generate all its JsonSerializable partial files in to ".g2.dart" files. What??
It appears that just executing the build_runner causes heaps of errors as a result.

Anybody familiar with how one is expected to contribute to this project?
I see no readme regarding how to build the codebase.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

omg. Crazy answer.

https://github.com/epam-cross-platform-lab/swagger-dart-code-generator/issues/388

`you can just remove .g2 to .g and make it .g2 again when generation is completed. Also before generation please comment build.yaml file, otherwise generation will not work`